# React Component not rendered in IE 10 or 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, polyfills

I have my react component which is working fine in firefox, chrome and Microsoft Edge but I get a blank page when I check it in IE 10 or IE 11. I understood that it has to do something with polyfills.So I defined a polyfill function, Is my configuration proper? What might I be missing?

```
    'use strict';

    if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
  // Rejection tracking prevents a common issue where React gets into an
 // inconsistent state due to an error, but it gets swallowed by a Promise,
// and the user has no idea what causes React's erratic future behavior.

      require('promise/lib/rejection-tracking').enable();
      window.Promise = require('promise/lib/es6-extensions.js');
    }

    // fetch() polyfill for making API calls.
    require('whatwg-fetch');

 // Object.assign() is commonly used with React.
// It will use the native implementation if it's present and isn't buggy.
    Object.assign = require('object-assign');
```